# How to check multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a search my database called 'songs' and it got an average of 60 tables, all columns have the same name (id, name, data).

```
SELECT * FROM (all tables in my DB songs) WHERE name LIKE 'a%';
```

How do I get the records that meet the condition "where" of all the tables?

Comment: SELECT * FROM (table1, table2, table3,....) WHERE name LIKE 'a%';

Comment: This is why [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is an important thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though `UNION` should be what you should go for but you can also do like below (an example)

```
select * from sample1,sample3,sample4 
where sample1.name like 'M%'
and sample3.name like 'M%'
and sample4.name like 'M%'
```

Moreover, if all 60 tables have same columns (as you mentioned) then what is the point in maintaining those many table? Why not a single table?

Comment: Because they are 60  genres

Comment: @GeordiRamirezEgoavil, in that case just make another table for `genres` and while quering just do a join between the tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION`

```
  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name LIKE 'a%' 
  UNION 
  SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE name LIKE 'a%' ;
```

And on...

**The question here is why do you have 60 same tables?**

Comment: Because they are 60 music genres

Comment: @GeordiRamirezEgoavil then you add a `genres` table with `id, name` and 1 songs table with one additinal column `id_genres` referencing `id` in genres table.

Answer (score 0):

To get all tables with columns 'id' or 'name' or 'data' in the database 'songs'

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME
IN (
'id',  'name', 'data'
)
AND TABLE_SCHEMA =  'songs'
```

I can not think why there are 60 tables ?

Comment: I am not sure how does this answer relates to the question being asked.

Comment: using this query we can get all the table names into a variable and then we can use that variable to the select query where in question